# What is the effect of np.stack([a, b, c, axis=-1)?

Tags: python, numpy

I have three pictures (a, b, c) and each is a size of 100x100.
What is the effect of the following code:

```
final = np.stack([a, b, c, axis=-1)

final.shape
>>> (1, 100, 100, 3)
```

How do I have to visualize the outcome (final) graphically? Is fig a) or b) (or something else) correct?

[image]

Comment: `b)` is definitely much closer to the truth than `a)`

Comment: If `a`, `b` and `c` all have shape `(100, 100)`, then `np.stack([a, b, c], axis=-1)` would have shape `(100, 100, 3)`, not `(1, 100, 100, 3)`.

Comment: You'll gt a `syntax error`.  You are missing a ']'.  A (1,100,100,3) shape means that the 3 arrays are (1,100,100).  `stack` keeps them separate, joined on a new axis.  There's no one way to visualize such a result.

Comment: With (1,100,100) arrays, consider using `np.concatenate([a,b,c], axis=0)` to make a (3,100,100).